# $\left<2,x\right>$ is a maximal ideal of $\Bbb Z[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

> I want to show that $\left<2,x\right>$ is a maximal ideal of $\Bbb Z[x]$.

My game plan is to use the 3rd isomorphism theorem to somehow get that $Z[x]/\left<2,x\right>$ isomorphic to $Z_2$ (since every this would mean that $Z[x]/\left<2,x\right>$ is a field and hence $\left<2,x\right>$ would be a maximal ideal) but I'm not entirely sure how to arrive at that conclusion.

My first thoughts are that since $\left<x\right>$ is an ideal of $Z[x]$ and $\left<x\right>\subset\left<2,x\right>$ we have that $Z[x]/\left<2,x\right> \cong Z[x]/\left<x\right>/\left<2,x\right>/\left<x\right>$ by the 3rd isomorphism theorem, but I'm not sure if this is the right direction. Any hints or tips would be great.

Comment: That probably works. I'd personally go with something more direct, using this idea: In any commutative ring $R$, an ideal $I \subseteq R$ is maximal if and only if for all $f \in R$ with $f \notin I$, there exists $g \in I$ such that $f + g = 1$. (In other words, an ideal is maximal if and only if adding in anything more gives the ideal $(1) = R$.) But that's mostly a matter of taste, since both methods amount to the same thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems like a possible direction. As a next step, you can say that:
$$ \mathbb{Z}[x]/(2,x) \simeq \left(  \mathbb{Z}[x]/(x)\right) /\left((2,x)/(x) \right) \simeq  \mathbb{Z}/(2) = \mathbb{Z}_2,$$
and you're done. The second isomorphism needs some justification, perhaps. This would involve either waiving your hands around it, or doing it by hand.

You can also refer to the [second isomorphism theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorem#Second_isomorphism_theorem_2). Because $ \mathbb{Z}[x] =  \mathbb{Z} + (2,x)$, we have that:
$$   \mathbb{Z}[x]/(2,x) = \left(  \mathbb{Z} + (2,x) \right) /(2,x) \simeq  \mathbb{Z}/\left(  \mathbb{Z} \cap (2,x) \right) \simeq  \mathbb{Z}/(2) = \mathbb{Z}_2.$$

Comment: That's the thing, I'm not sure how to make that 2nd isomorphism work. Should I just do it from straight definition?

Comment: @user23793 Ah, OK. See if the edited version suits you better.

Comment: I see! This problem has been bugging me for a couple of days. Thank you for the assistance.

Comment: @user It means sum of (sub)rings. If $A,B \subset R$ are subrings of a ring $R$ then $A+B = \{a+b \ : \ a \in A,\ b \in B\}$, and it's a subring if $B$ is an ideal.

Answer (score 2):

You can look at something constructive, if you may. Note that $P\in\Bbb Z[X]$ is in $(2,X)$ if and only if its constant coefficient is divisible by $2$, that is, the elements of $(2,X)$ are of the form $2a_0+XP$ with $a_0\in\Bbb Z$ and $P\in\Bbb Z[X]$. Then consider the surjective homomorphism $\Bbb Z[X]\to \Bbb Z/(2)$ given by $P\mapsto { P(0)}+(2)$, and recall $\Bbb Z/(2)$ is a field.

In general, we have that $$\frac{R[x]}{(I,x)}\simeq \frac{R}{I}$$

Comment: I'm sorry, but the notation here "$\widehat{P(0)}$" means what exactly? I like that you said this because I thought about this but didn't think it would work.

Comment: @user23793 I mean the class of $P(0)$ (an integer) in $\Bbb Z/(2)$. Edited to a better notation.

Comment: Oh, I think I see it now. Are you thinking of using the 1st iso theorem? If I did the work correctly, the kernel of this mapping $\left<2,x\right>$, correct?

Comment: @user23793 Yes, that is it.